# Android Sqlite Database is modifiable outside my app?

Tags: android, sqlite, security, android-sqlite

Is it possible to update SQLite database of android app outside app?I mean can user modify database according to them where the database situates in default location?

Comment: I mean, they always could as long as they have access to the device. The question is how motivated they are to get there. Suppose they put the device in developer mode, for example, and try connecting to the database via API calls. They'll have to work around any nuances in the android sdk. And as long as I have the data all I need is a tool to help me read/write that data. What specifically is your concern in this area?

Answer (score 1):

The default location is in /data/data/your-package/databases which is only accessible from your application. No other application is able to access it.

However in some special cases like rooted device, debug mode etc , it is still possible to access the database file and change it.

Comment: There is one exception how users can access the database on unrooted devices: using the backup functionality. If backup is allowed for the app (in AndroidManifest.xml) you can make a backup, extract it on a PC, modify the database, pack it and then restore the backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the DB using [Content Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics) if you want to access it programmatically. Or If you just want to browse the data then you can follow [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-view-and-locate-sqlite-database-in-android-studio/) post.